# Can I use akka in existing J2ee application that is running on weblogic server. Most of the requests are stateful in this application

Tags: akka

I have a j2ee based application. Most of the requests to this application area stateful. And the database connectivity is via JDBC. Can I use akka in this application for some of the use-cases/requests?

Comment: The short answer is yes - however J2EE suggests you may using an old version Java in which case Akka may not be supported. Also it may be worth describing your use-cases so further advice can be provided.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have enterprise application based on jee deployed on weblogic. If we plan use akka for few services in the application, how can we intergrate the existing jee app with these new akka services? Also if we need consulting approach to try this use case, does akka community have any support for this?